# how to implement draggable pins using OS 3.1 MapKit?

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

I am Working on a map kit in ios 4.1 but when i am build my app on a ios 3.1 so it give annotation error

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState
```

this function is not is 3.1

Regard

Shazli

Answer (score 0):

The native dragging support indeed requires iOS 4 or later. Fortunately, there's a [Legacy Map Techniques document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/EarlyDraggableAnnotations/EarlyDraggableAnnotations.html) describing how to create draggable annotations in earlier versions of iOS.